# excel 2016 - frequency formula - data array move by one row

Tags: arrays, excel-formula, frequency

I have approx. 100 rows by 60 columns with numbers which I'd need to be arranged in (same) bins categories. (12 bins)

In a new sheet, I used the frequency formula to look at the first row and return in an array in a column the distribution in bins. It worked for the first row of the source data but now I'd like that when I drag the formula to the next column, the data array in the frequency formula to move to the next row of the data source and return the distribution by bins.

Is it possible, can you please help with this one? Or is there any other way I can do such a bin arrangement? Need frequencies for A, B,C etc..and would like to drag the formula to the right, if that is possible.

partial data-distributed horizontally
[image: partial data-distributed horizontally]

Comment: Please show what you are working on and what you used then it may be possible to find the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following formula for `Column U`:

```
=FREQUENCY(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(COLUMN()-19,3) & ":" & ADDRESS(COLUMN()-19,18)),$T$3:$T$17)
```

and drag/copy across as required. For details on `INDIRECT` function see [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDIRECT-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261).

**Note:** `INDIRECT` is a volatile function and hence is recalculated every time anything changes in the worksheet.

See image for results based on data provided by you.

[image]